# Undefined reference to a static const struct

Tags: c++, struct, static, constants

I have this header (with hidden code):

```
class DrawBuffers
{
public:
struct CubeCorners
{
    GLfloat corners[NUM_VERTS * ELEM_PER_NORM];
    CubeCorners(bool normalize);
};

static const CubeCorners POSITIONS;
static const GLfloat COLOR_DEFAULT[ELEM_PER_COLOR];
static const CubeCorners NORMALS;
static const GLuint INDICES[NUM_INDICES / NB_FACES][NB_INDICES_PER_FACE];
};
```

I have this in the cpp:

```
const DrawBuffers::CubeCorners POSITIONS = DrawBuffers::CubeCorners(false);
const GLfloat DrawBuffers::COLOR_DEFAULT[] = {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
const DrawBuffers::CubeCorners NORMALS = DrawBuffers::CubeCorners(true);
const GLuint DrawBuffers::INDICES[][NB_INDICES_PER_FACE] = { //second indices
{0, 1, 2, // Back
2, 3, 0},

{7, 6, 5, // Front
5, 4, 7},

{4, 5, 1, // Left
1, 0, 4},

{3, 2, 6, // Right
6, 7, 3},

{4, 0, 3, // Bottom
3, 7, 4},

{6, 2, 1, // Top
1, 5, 6}};
```

And I still get an undefined reference to POSITIONS in the same .cpp file... Anything I may have forgotten?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are static members, so you need to qualify the names in their definitions (as you've already done with two of them):

```
const DrawBuffers::CubeCorners DrawBuffers::POSITIONS = DrawBuffers::CubeCorners(false);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You've instead declared static non-member variables.

Comment: Omg I'm so retarded. Thank you very much! I didn't sleep because of this.